# Firefox support carousel bootstrap v4.0??

Tags: bootstrap-4

I fired the carousel bootstrap v4.0 example on firefox browser. The images-item doesn't slide!

I think it is a Bootstrap bug.

So, Firefox support carousel bootstrap v4.0??

This is the example:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Proof</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.0.0-beta\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- messo prima di style.css altrimenti annulla la formattazione di base -->
     
     <!-- per il menu smartphone -->
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
     </head>

     <body style="background:#000">
      <div id="carouselEvents" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
       <div class="carousel-inner" style="height:100%">
         <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="invernale.jpg" alt="concerto"/>
         </div>
         <!-- second slide events -->
         <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="estivo.jpg" alt="concerto"/>
         </div>
         <!-- third slide events -->
         <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="invernale.jpg" alt="concerto"/>
         </div>
       </div>
       <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselEvents" role="button" data-slide="prev">
         <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
       </a>
       <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselEvents" role="button" data-slide="next">
         <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
       </a>
     </div>
      
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-beta\dist\js"></script>
     
   </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using backslashes\ in your href links
change them to forward slash **/**

Comment: Even though I change the slash carousel bootstrap does not work in firefox!

Answer (score 0):

use this before the `</body>` tag and delete your links to your local storage of these

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

"I think it is a Bootstrap bug in FF." 
NO! I'm the bug:

```
<script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-beta\dist\js"></script>
```

the path was incorret!
The correct src is:

```
<script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-beta\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you mlegg!